# How do I push to a fork that isn't mine?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

There's a project I've started maintaining. I'm in a situation where one contributor has forked and then made a PR to the original repository.

There are a few related changes I'd like to make in addition before I merge their changes in, so I'd like to push to their fork then merge once everything is OK. Is this something possible on GitHub, or is there a separate process for this use case?

Comment: Why don't you ask the contributor to make the changes needed before you're prepared to merge? Or do you mean changes unrelated to theirs?

Comment: @jonrsharpe They haven't been responsive so I wanted to help out. I'm not sure what you mean by changes separate to theirs. Does it matter? I just want to make more changes in addition to the changes they have made before I merge.

Okay I just saw your edit. I want to make related changes in addition to theirs.

Comment: You could fork their modified fork, make the changes and merge that. My question is: are those *"additional changes"* actually related to the PR, or not? It doesn't matter in the long run, but it's good to be logically consistent.

Comment: "I want to make related changes in addition to theirs".

Comment: You can check out their branch locally (GitHub even tells you how to do that when you click on the "Merge manually" link in the PR). Then make your additional changes locally in that branch, commit them, then merge them into the main project. Or create another PR based on the combined changes and merge that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply said: this is not possible. You are trying to modify a fork of a project someone else had forked. You want to maintain the changes of the fork relative to the originally forked project? So the situation is as follows:

- A = Original Repo
- B fork of A
- C = Fork of B

You can do the following to get the changes of project B.

1. Fork project B, so you will get C.
2. Change the code you would want to.
3. Sent a pull request from C to B.

Step three isn't even necessary. You can get the changes that were made in B by pulling in the changes once they are made (in case the contributors in B are not cooperative).